# How can I compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty I(t) \lambda (dt)$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty I^2(t) \lambda (dt)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

The Question is,

Compute $E(X)$, $E(X^2)$ and $Var(X)$, where the law of X is given by

$L(X)= {1 \over 2} \delta_1 + {1\over 2} \lambda$, where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$.

The Solution is, when $I(t)=t$,

$E_P(X)= {1 \over 2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty I(t) \delta_1 (dt) + {1 \over 2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty I(t) \lambda (dt)= {1 \over 2}(1) + {1\over2}({1\over2})={3\over4}$

$E_P(X^2)={1 \over 2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty I^2(t) \delta_1 (dt) + {1 \over 2} \int_{-\infty}^\infty I^2(t) \lambda (dt)= {1 \over 2}(1) + {1\over2}({1\over 3})={2\over3}$

$Var(X)=E_P(X^2)-E_P^2(X)={5 \over 48}$

But the solution is above my head.

How can I compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty I(t) \lambda (dt)$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty I^2(t) \lambda (dt)$?

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of calculus, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty I(t)\lambda(dt) = \int_0^1t\, dt=\left[\frac{1}{2}t^2\right]^1_0=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Just remember to insert the definitions of $I(t)$ and $\lambda$ and you obtain a Riemannian integral.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Is it ok to think that $\lambda( )$ restricts the domain of the integral?

Comment: Yes, it is. In drhab's answer you find the reason why it is okay to do so.

Comment: @Y.Kim random variable $X$ induces a measure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$. This measure is $\delta_1+\mu$ where $\mu$ is prescribed by $A\mapsto\lambda(A\cap[0,1])$ and $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Y.Kim If this answer is enough for you then you should also accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Here what you call "the Lebesguemeasure on $[0,1]$" is actually the measure prescribed by $A\mapsto\lambda (A\cap[0,1])$  where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesguemeasure.

Then: $$\mathsf Ef(X)=\frac12\int f(t)\delta_1(dt)+\frac12\int f(t)\lambda(dt)=\frac12f(1)+\frac12\int_{[0,1]} f(t)dt$$

Can you find $\int_{[0,1]} tdt$ and $\int_{[0,1]} t^2dt$  yourself?

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your answer is so clear!!!!! I think I can find the other things myself. Thank you, again.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: Sorry, but can I ask you another question?
If I compute $\int_{-\infty}^\infty I(t) \mu_N(dt)$ where $\mu_N$ is the standard normal distribution, 
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty I(t) \mu_N(dt)=I(E(\mu_N))=0$
Is this right?

Comment: In general rv $X$ induces a measure $\mu_X$ on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$. This measure $\mu_X$ is prescribed by $A\mapsto\mathsf P(X\in A)$. If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a suitable function then $\mathbb Ef(X)=\int f(t)\mu_X(dt)$. If $X$ has standard normal distribution and $I(t)=t$ then $0=\mathbb EX=\mathbb EI(X)=\int I(t)\mu_X(dt)$.

Comment: Oh I got it !! Thanks. Now I'll go trying to apply these to other distributions.